# What is the best way to parse a tuple from a string in Python?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, string-parsing

I tried this:

```
def string_to_value(self, old_value, distribution_type, new_value_str):
    parameter_names = distribution_type.parameters  # a list of string
    try:
        parameter_values = ast.literal_eval(new_value_str)  # a tuple or basic type hopefully
    except SyntaxError:
        raise ValueError('Syntax error during parse')
    retval = copy.copy(old_value)
    try:
        if len(parameter_names) == 1:
            setattr(retval, parameter_names[0], parameter_values)
        else:
            if len(parameter_names) != len(parameter_values):
                raise BoostPythonArgumentError
            for parm_name, parm_value in zip(parameter_names,
                                             parameter_values):
                setattr(retval, parm_name, parm_value)
    except BoostPythonArgumentError:
        raise ValueError('Lots of helpful text here')
    return retval
```

This works for a lot of cases.  Boost.Python automatically checks the type of `parm_value` at set time.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work on strings containing 'inf'.  `ast.literal_eval` raises `ValueError('malformed string')` when I would like it to return a float.  I don't understand how Python can parse 'inf', but literal_eval can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and [this PEP about evaluating **inf**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/#id5). I guess they will help

Comment: Thanks.  This gets me closer.  But, I'd like to use literal_eval instead of eval.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to evaluate? e.g.

```
a = "(1,2,3,4)"
b = tuple(a.strip('( )').split(','))
assert ('1','2','3','4') == b
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the elements have the same numeric type, then this works:

```
numpy.fromstring('1.3, 2.2, 5, inf, 2', sep=',')
```

returns

```
array([ 1.3,  2.2,  5. ,  inf,  2. ])
```